# How to referesh the page after an image is deleted in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this strange problem, may be I missed at something in the code.

When I delete an image, it is deleted fine but stays on the page. I know this because when I refresh the page it is no longer there.

But what I want is to reload page automatically somehow when delete function is executed because if user would delete again (that deleted image), this would show an error.

Controller:

```
function property_image_delete() {
  if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
    $username = $this->session->userdata('v_member_username');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $image = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['images_urls'] = $this->my_listings_model->get_property_all_images_url($id);
    $result = $this->my_listings_model->get_property_all_images_url($id);
    if (count($result) > 1) {
      $this->my_listings_model->delete_selected_property_image($id, $image, $data);
      $data['title'] = 'Image Deleted';
      $this->load->model('admin/my_profile_model');
      $this->load->view('headfoot/header-dashboard', $data);
    } else {
      $data['title'] = 'Error';
      $this->load->model('admin/my_profile_model');
      $data['error_no_delete'] = 'Can\'t delete it! There should be minimum 1 image left.';
      $this->load->view('headfoot/header-dashboard', $data);
    }
  } else // Some Code
```

Model:

```
function get_property_all_images_url($id) {
  $this->db->select('property_images');
  $this->db->from('vbc_property_images');
  $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $query_result = $query->result_array();
  if (empty($query_result)) {
    return FALSE;
  } elseif (count($query_result) > 1) {
    return 0;
  } else{
    $rowId = explode(',',$query_result[0]['property_images']);
    return $rowId;
  }
}

function delete_selected_property_image($id, $image, $data) {
  $delete = $image;
  $newColumn = '';
  foreach ($data['images_urls'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != $delete) {
      $newColumn[] = $value;
    }
  }
  $newUpdatedData = implode(",", $newColumn);
  $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
  $this->db->set(array('property_images'=>$newUpdatedData));
  $this->db->update('vbc_property_images');
  unlink('uploads/property-images/'.$image);
  return TRUE;
}
```

Is there a way that the page can be refreshed on it's own?

Comment: Why not use `redirect();` ?

Comment: Thanks @Kisaragi.. Yes I thought of that but not sure how to redirect along with my `$data`.. Could you please show a single line statement to do that.. I know this one `$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Authentication failed');` but don't know how to pass $data..

Comment: Store it in the session: `this->session->set_userdata('index', $data);`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Kisaragi.. It is working now the way I wanted..

Comment: The simple way is after deleting successfully add some javascript code to make image tag empty or replace the deleted img src with unknown image file.It does not need to refresh the page